# What does this weird javascript with the id "waxCS" code do?

Tags: javascript

I have seen the code:

```
var WAX = function () {
    var _arrInputs;
    window.addEventListener('waxSetArr', function(evt) {
        _arrInputs = evt.detail;
    });
    return {
        getElement: function (i) {
            return _arrInputs[i];
        }
    }
}();
function waxGetElement(i) {
    return WAX.getElement(i);
}
```

I found this piece of weird javascript code on my website even though I didn't mean to add it. I have searched all over the internet about what it does. I still can't really get what it does. What does this code do and could someone explain it to me?

Comment: A google points at Norton WAX: means Web Analysis eXpert Engine is responsible for detecting,capturing  and autofilling  the logins filelds, form fields.

Comment: ... make my ears bleed ... but seriously why not add a few new lines to it?

Comment: @EdHeal Give it some times, I edited it... still needs peer review. EDIT: Aww. Some other editor's changes were accepted... Mine looked nicer.

Comment: @Derija93 - Lucky you!

Comment: @EdHeal Well, the new edit looks like mine now. Phew.

Comment: @Derija93 - Yes I agreed yours looked nicer so I just copied and pasted it. Unfortunately you don't get the 2 points for an accepted edit though.

Comment: @MartinSmith Ah. Well, doesn't really matter to me. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Added a few comments explaining the code itself.  Can't tell you what it actually does in the context of the page you have, as there is not enough information, but you should be able to figure it out.

```
    //Creates a function and assigns it to the variable WAX.  This is then
    //also called at this point.
    var WAX = function () {
      var _arrInputs;

      //Adds an event listener - when 'waxSetArr' is raised
      //this will set the _arrInputs to equal the evt.detail.
      //(Which would give the appearance of being an array).
      window.addEventListener('waxSetArr', function(evt) {
        _arrInputs = evt.detail;
      });

      //Returns a function, that when called will return the item
      //in the array at index i.
      return {
        getElement: function (i) {
            return _arrInputs[i];
        }
     }
   }();

   //Calls the function stored in the variable above - returns the element
   //at index i (if it exists).
   function waxGetElement(i) {
      return WAX.getElement(i);
   }
```